# Nesting in HTML5

Tags: html

My understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the "section" tag in html5 is used somewhat like a wrapper div. If that is correct, ok, fine, no prob.  But what about nesting? As we all know, its quite common to nest divs inside of each other.  Does this mean in html5 we next "section" instead?

Comment: @Jin your right. Nesting is fine as long as your using a minimal amount of tags.

Comment: Yup, thank you. After further research I found this valuable resource: [http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element), which does advocate the use of div over section, given the situation. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 7):

Sections can be and should be nested if the content indicates so. See for example http://www.mattryall.net/blog/2008/10/html-5-headings-and-sections and  http://blog.whatwg.org/is-not-just-a-semantic

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) (emphasis mine):

> The DIV and SPAN elements, in conjunction with the id and class attributes, offer a generic mechanism for adding structure to documents. These elements define content to be inline (SPAN) or block-level (DIV) *but impose no other presentational idioms on the content*

Divs carry no semantic meaning about the content. Sections do. Sections therefor can and should be nested if the content requires it, like when formatting a classic chapter-paragraph-structure. 
Sections should *not* be used as hooks for purely technical matters. Divs are still the way to go for that.

Comment: I guess I'm still left wondering... Ok, here's an example: Wrapper - > two floating divs inside of the wrapper -> stuff two divs in the left wrapper, stacked, same in the right floated div.  In this case why would I use the section tag?  In this case divs have always been used more like a building block than anything.

Comment: you don't need to use the section tag. Divs are still entirely acceptable for certain structures but not really if you want/need/should have logical structures.

Answer (score 1):

You should not nest html5 elements the way you are describing... like so:

```
  <section>
    <section>
      <section>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <p>...</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
```

One of the most common mistakes is nesting or wrapping article elements with the section element, like so:

```
<section>
  <article>
    ...
  </article>
</section>
<section>
  <article>
    ...
  </article>
</section>
```

You can separate into logical parts a section with articles and vice-versa, but the preceding code is most likely being used for stylizing and not semantics. In that case you should replace one or the other with a div element.

The proper way to nest elements in html5 is pretty much the way you might already be familiar with... one example:

```
<main>
  <div>
    <div>
      <section>
        <header>
          <h1></h1>
          <time datetime=""></time>
        </header>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```